# Como detectar conexão USB via aplicação?

Tags: java, android

É possível eu detectar uma conexão USB em minha aplicação Android e como fazer isso?

Tenho um menu de sincronismo que é realizado via USB e FTP, porém eu quero deixar a opção de USB acessível somente quando o aparelho estiver conectado ao PC via USB.

Vi algo sobre USBManager, mas não achei nada que pudesse me ajudar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Na *Activity* que tem esse menu faça o seguinte:

Declare uma classe derivada de `BroadcastReceiver`

```
public class UsbDeviceDetect extends BroadcastReceiver { 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED")) {

                //Aqui torne enable o seu item de menu
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED")) {

                //Aqui torne disable o seu item menu
        }
    } 
}
```

Declare dois atributos, um para o `BroadcastReceiver` e outro para o `IntentFilter`

```
private UsbDeviceDetect usbDeviceDetect;
private IntentFilter filter;
```

No método `onCreate` crie uma instância do `BroadcastReceiver` e o respetivo `IntentFilter`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ----------
    UsbDeviceDetect usbDeviceDetect = new UsbDeviceDetect();
    filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED");
    filter.addAction("android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED");

}
```

No método `onResume` registe o `BroadcastReceiver`

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    registerReceiver(usbDeviceDetect, filter));
}
```

No método `onPause` faça o *unregister* do `BroadcastReceiver`

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    unregisterReceiver(usbDeviceDetect);

    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que o que você deseja está [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13429157/221800) no SO:

```
<receiver android:name=".DetactUSB">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Código:

```
public class DetactUSB extends BroadcastReceiver { 
    private static final String TAG = "DetactUSB";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_CONNECTED")) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                textView.setText("USB connected……….");
                Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
                toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                toastView.setView(textView);
                toastView.show();
                Log.i(TAG,"USB connected..");
        }
        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase( "android.intent.action.UMS_DISCONNECTED")) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(context);
                textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                textView.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                textView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
                textView.setText("USB Disconnected……….");
                Toast toastView = new Toast(context);
                toastView.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toastView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                toastView.setView(textView);
                toastView.show();
        }
    } 
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/UsbDetect.java).

Se isto é não exatamente o que você quer talvez possa fazer uma adaptação para usar outra ação conforme [essa outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12841332/221800) no SO:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
</intent-filter>
```

[Documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html#example).